# Why I encounter error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'type'

Tags: python, llvmlite

I am using llvmlite for my project in combination with Pyvex. I have defined some functions in llvmlite like the following:

```
def int32(val): 
    return ir.Constant(ir.IntType(32), val)


def put64(putoffset, val):
    llvmtmp = builder.gep(regtag, (int32(0), int32(putoffset)), True)
    return builder.store(val, llvmtmp)
```

However, when I want to call this function using the following code:

```
for stmt in irsb.statements:
   if isinstance(stmt, pyvex.IRStmt.Put):
      putoffset = stmt.offset
      put64("t3", putoffset)
```

I encounter the error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'type'

does anyone know how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: do you mean to call `put64(putoffset,"t3")` instead?

Comment: if I do this, then I encounter the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: are you using python 3? also int32() is not a python native function did you define it somewhere in the program or you import it? it will be helpful to have more code to work with.

Comment: My python version is 2.7.9. Yes, the function for that is :def int32(val):
    return ir.Constant(ir.IntType(32), val)

Comment: thank you for posting more code but now what is `ir`?

Comment: ir and constants are module from llvmlite. We have the following for ir:   from llvmlite import ir

Comment: Please post the full error stack trace. It’s impossible to tell where the error comes from. Also, that is very little code.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little digging. The problem is happening on this line

`return ir.Constant(ir.IntType(32), val)` in your `int32()` function.

Constant is defined as such in llvmlite:

```
 Constant(typ, constant)
```

*typ* is the type of the represented value
       (a :class:`~llvmlite.ir.Type` instance).  *constant* is the Python
       value to be represented.  Which Python types are allowed for *constant*
       Which Python types are allowed for constant depends on typ.

Instead of passing in Python types you just pass in `int` and `string` as `val`. try put `type()` around it.

```
return ir.Constant(ir.IntType(32), type(val))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you but this did not help. Do you want to see my whole code?

Comment: yes that would be very helpful especially for debugging purpose.

Comment: May I have your email?

Comment: it is listed on my profile but here you go: awesomeoliverkoo@gmail.com

Comment: in case if it goes to spam. Leave a comment here when you sent it so I will look for it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem. Actually the problem is that we are passing a string to the function but it needs to be an llvmlite object. Hence python complains that strings don't have an attribute type. Passing llvmlite object, the problem would be solved.